# Getting JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to build a random quote machine. I have an API and I am struggling passing JSON data to my HTML. If I follow an API link I am getting the needed JSON, but for some reason it's not being passed to HTML.

```js
function ran_col() {
  let color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
  let letters = ['b3cffc', 'b3fcd2', 'fcfbb3', 'fcc3b3', 'c5b3fc', 'b3c3fc', 'b3fcdb', 'b5fcb3']; //Set your colors here
  color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
}

function getQuote() {

  $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=json&lang=en", function(data) {

    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);

  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  ran_col();
  getQuote();
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 html,
body,
.container-table {
  height: 100%;
}
.container-table {
  display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-table">
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">
    <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
      <div id="text">TEXT</div>
      <footer><cite>Author</cite>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: Look in the web console. Unless the origin of your page is granted access by that API's endpoint, you'll see an error saying access was denied. The linked question's answers explain why.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you